# how to Bucket automatically propagate to files AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

From AWS doc http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--access-control-list-acl-overview.html that 'Permission set for a Bucket does NOT automatically propagate to files stored in that Bucket.' Any idea how to configure that allow files under the bucket have the same access permissions of the bucket?

Regards
Hammer

Comment: this is not aws docs, lol

Comment: The link is NOTa link to the  AWS documentation.  It is a link to documentation to a 3rd party product.  Are you asking about that product, or are you askong about S3?

Comment: sorry, i have not realised this is from 3rd party. My problem is with S3.

Comment: If you want to set complex permissions on S3, please refer to policy examples (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) and the policy generator (http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html). From there, all you need to do is set the appropriate ARN (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) for sub-folders.